# making a client server application of sales inventory system including sql database in c#

Tags: sql-server, client-server

i am a beginer and i am making a client server application in c# using sql database.
i am using just two computers, at one computer i want to store my database as well as the application will also run on the same computer it one computer is the server and the client both and the another computer will be a simple client that will access the database.
can any one help me how shoud i write the code for both systems to connect the database.
thank you.

Comment: This is a very broad and very general question.... it's really hard to give you any meaningful answer here..... first you need to design your basic system architecture, and then you need to define your server-side application (incl. database) and your client side application, and then build them.... come back and ask more specific questions, if you have them!

Answer (score 0):

To connect to SQL Server from C#.NET, you need to create a connection string such as below:

private SqlConnection connection;
private string connectionString =
@"Server=(local);Database=Embedding_SQL_Test;User ID=sa;Password=123";
connection = new SqlConnection( connectionString );

Next, you use the SqlConnection object created above to create a 'SqlCommand', as shown below:
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "select * from Customer where CustomerID = @Cid", connection);

The SQL query shown here can be replaced by a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE queries etc.

Next to execute the SQL queries in the database, you use the following methods:
ExecuteReader - to execute SELECT queries
ExecuteNonQuery - to execute INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, and SET statements.

This is a very short description of how to connect to SQL Server database from C# and execute SQL queries in the database.
For details about the connection string, the methods and their parameters check the following link: ( http://www.shahriarnk.com/Shahriar-N-K-Research-Embedding-SQL-in-C-Sharp-Java.html )
Here you will also find details about how to pass parameters to the SQL queries as well as calling stored procedures and much more.